# When NOT to use ECS architecture?

Tags: architecture, entity-system, component-based, entity-component, entity

I'm familiar with the notion of entity-component-system architecture, and its advantages over traditional class trees.  That being said, **are there scenarios where one *wouldn't* want to use entity-component-system architecture?**

Comment: I upvoted because I'd be interested in answers. However, I also voted to close, as this is primarily opinion based.